# Is it possible to destroy a village?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have made an iron farm (Copied Mumbo's iron farm from Hermitcraft S7) and I read something about villages having to be 150 blocks from the iron farm for it to function efficiently. I only read this after building it though, and there's a village about 120 blocks from the edge of the farm, and I cannot be arsed to rebuild it, so I instead thought it might be possible to get rid of the village? (I destroyed all the beds, workstations, doors, bells, houses and everything I could see that was village related)

Answer (score 4):

In 1.14 the Village mechanics got reworked, and the definition of a Village is the following:

> A village needs at least one house and at least one villager in order
> to be a "village". A "house" is a bed.
>
> https://minecraft.wiki/w/Village/Mechanics#House

In older versions:

> A village needs at least one house and at least one villager in order
> to be a "village". A "house" is defined simply as a wooden door with
> an "inside" and an "outside".
>
> https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Legacy_Console_village_mechanics#Terminology

If you've destroyed everything (including the Villagers), then the game should consider the village non-existent, and therefore it shouldn't interfere with your contraptions.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do the following:

- Destroy all bells
- Destroy all beds
- Destroy all doors (if below 1.14)
- Destroy the workstations (barrels, composters, stonecutters, etc)
- Kill all villagers

Answer (score 2):

My first tip is make sure there are absolutely ***no*** villagers alive, and there is no proof that a village existed, ie., not a single piece of wood. As @Andruida mentioned, a village needs at least one house and villager to be functioning.

After that, I don't think it's a good idea to copy Mumbo, because he didn't make a tutorial video so he didn't explain everything, and so he might've changed some stuff of camera or you missed this *one* tiny block. He put a link to the tutorial he followed, so you can check that out if you want to build you're own iron farm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but if not doing it properly then the golems will keep re spawning

Comment: so how do I do it properly? there's no villagers there anymore, and it wasn't a big enough village to spawn any golems anyway

Comment: By keeping them away or move it somewhere